# Regex read html values

Tags: c#, regex

I have this file that contains the following text (html):

```
<tr> 
<th scope="row">X:</th> 
<td>343</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<th scope="row">Y:</th> 
<td>6,995 sq ft / 0.16 acres</td> 
</tr>
```

And I have this method to read the values from X,Y

```
        private static Dictionary<string, string> FindKeys(IEnumerable<string> keywords, string source)
    {
        var found = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var keys = string.Join("|", keywords.ToArray());
        var matches = Regex.Matches(source, @"\b(?<key>" + keys + @"):\s*(?<value>)");

        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            try
            {
                var key = m.Groups["key"].ToString();
                var value = m.Groups["value"].ToString();
                found.Add(key, value);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

I can't get the method to return the values from X,Y

Any thing wrong in the regex expression?

Comment: Ordinarily, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

You have "" between keyword and value so you need to skip them in your regex like this:

```
\b(?<key>" + keys + @"):\s*</th>[^<]*<td>(?<value>[^<]*)
```

And BTW, you need to specify the pattern for "value" - I've specified it as [^<]*.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you know, parsing HTML with a regex is never fun.  You current regex does not look very close to capturing what your looking for.  As such I would recommend two possible alternatives...

Option 1 - If adding a library is acceptable, use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It's blazing fast and very accurate.

Option 2 - If your looking for lighter-weight solution, [these source files](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/trunk/src/Library/Html/XmlLightParser.cs) contain a regex parser for xml/html.  To use directly, implement the [IXmlLightReader](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/trunk/src/Library/Html/XmlLightInterfaces.cs) then call the [XmlLightParser.Parse](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/trunk/src/Library/Html/XmlLightParser.cs#101) method.  If your document is a complete HTML document and not a fragment, you can also use the [HtmlLightDocument](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/trunk/src/Library/Html/HtmlLightDocument.cs) as follows:

```
HtmlLightDocument doc = new HtmlLightDocument(@"<html> ... </html>");
foreach(XmlLightElement row in doc.Select(@"//tr"))
    found.Add(
        row.SelectSingleNode(@"th").InnerText, 
        row.SelectSingleNode(@"td").InnerText
    );
```

Option 3 - As always, if the html is xhtml compliant then you can just use an xml parser.